# Background transparent and foreground darker

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency, android-relativelayout

I have something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
tools:context="com.example.budgetme.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

How do make the "android:background="@drawable/blue_bg" transparent and the other buttons,Textviews,etc more darker and more "SEEN"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want? explain clearly..

Comment: you can use color code with alpha value to make it transparent like `android:background="#550000FF"` here first two characters represent alpha value and rest 6 characters represent color code.

Comment: `android:alpha="0.40"` makes background translucent.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alpha="0.8"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"
tools:context="com.example.budgetme.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

you can set more transparency by setting value android:alpha="0 to 1"

Comment: This is making even the Textview that transparent.
I need only the background picture to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define your blue_bg in the colors.xml file. For example:

```
<color name="blue_bg">#??3f51b5</color>
```

where ?? you can replace with hex according to transparency i.e.

100% — FF , 
90% — E6 , 
80% — CC ,
70% — B3 ,
60% — 99 ,
50% — 80 ,
40% — 66 ,
30% — 4D ,
20% — 33 ,
10% — 1A ,
0% — 00

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable-> blue_bg
replace (say u use the following color code)

```
<solid android:color="#462D85" />
```

to

```
<solid android:color="#4D462D85" />
```

for 70% transparency

rest opaque values are---

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```